# Reverse the order of a legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, reverse, legend

I use the following code to plot the bar graph and need to present a legend in reverse order. How can I do it?

```
colorsArr = plt.cm.BuPu(np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(C2)))
p = numpy.empty(len(C2), dtype=object)
plt.figure(figsize=(11, 11))

prevBar = 0
for index in range(len(C2)):
    plt.bar(ind, C2[index], width, bottom=prevBar, color=colorsArr[index],
            label=C0[index])
    prevBar = prevBar + C2[index]

# Positions of the x-axis ticks (center of the bars as bar labels)
tick_pos = [i + (width/2) for i in ind]

plt.ylabel('Home Category')
plt.title('Affinity - Retail Details(Home category)')

# Set the x ticks with names
plt.xticks(tick_pos, C1)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 70000, 3000))
plt.legend(title="Line", loc='upper left')

# Set a buffer around the edge
plt.xlim(-width*2, width*2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You could call

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], title='Line', loc='upper left')
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2016)

C0 = list('ABCDEF')
C2 = np.random.randint(20000, size=(len(C0), 3))
width = 1.0
C1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
ind = np.linspace(-width, width, len(C1))


colorsArr = plt.cm.BuPu(np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(C2)))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

prevBar = 0
for height, color, label in zip(C2, colorsArr, C0):
    h = ax.bar(ind, height, width, bottom=prevBar, color=color, label=label)
    prevBar = prevBar + height

plt.ylabel('Home Category')
plt.title('Affinity - Retail Details(Home category)')

# positions of the x-axis ticks (center of the bars as bar labels)
tick_pos = [i+(width/2.0) for i in ind]
# set the x ticks with names
plt.xticks(tick_pos, C1)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,70000,3000))

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], title='Line', loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Or you could use the simpler

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(reversed(handles), reversed(labels), title='Line', loc='upper left')
```

Comment: ax.legend(*map(reversed, ax.get_legend_handles_labels()), ...)

Comment: @user66081: Please explain your correction, as the original solution seems to work perfectly and is similar to the selected answer using indexing with negative step slices and no map either.

Comment: @mins: I suppose the reason was you don't need to remember which comes first and you can find get_legend_handles_labels in the list of suggestions by the IDE. "Plus", negative step slices are ugly.

Answer (score 14):

The newest version of matplotlib (>=3.7) now provides this feature out of the box:

```
plt.legend(title="Line", loc='upper left', reverse=True)
```

The default is `reverse=False` (the previous behaviour)—setting it to `reverse=True` will now show the entries in the legend in the same order as the stacked bars. See [Axes.legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend).

Answer (score 9):

Use a negative number for the legend vertical spacing, like this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot(X, *revDataValues,
    linewidth=1.0,
    edgecolor='black')

matplotlib.pyplot.legend(revNames,
    loc=6, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.5),
    labelspacing=-2.5, frameon=False,         # reverse legend
    fontsize=9.0)
```

[Stacked Area Chart with reversed legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtM36.png)

Comment: What is *revDataValues?

Comment: I don't think this works. I want to switch the items in the legend, not in the plot.

Comment: I love how elegant this is -- but it causes some items in my legend to fall outside the box.

Comment: This is the most under rated answer I've seen - Very elegant

Comment: Very elegant solution. frameon=False will sort the issue of the labels going outside the box

Answer (score 5):

I've not tested this as I don't have your data, but this is based on the documentation here on [controlling legend entries](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/users/legend_guide.html#controlling-the-legend-entries).

```
handles = []
for index in range(len(C2)):
    h = plt.bar(ind, C2[index], width, bottom=prevBar, color=colorsArr[index], label=C0[index])
    handles.append(h)
    prevBar = prevBar + C2[index]

plt.legend(title="Line", loc='upper left', handles=handles[::-1])
```

Comment: What is `C2` in this answer?

Comment: Same as `C2` in the question, I imagine

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_label'`

Comment: Just fixed with a comma: `h, = plt.plot[...]`