# Change the order of the legend in a plot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, legend, legend-properties

I have been trying to change the order of the legend on a plot in Pandas to get it in the same order as the plot appears:

[Screenshot of the code and the plot in Anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QSCX.png)

As you see, the plots are stacking by increasing the amount of %K and I would like the legend to be reversed so the plot can be easier to read.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide code in your topic (not just screen)?

Answer (score 0):

You can call this before the loop:

```
 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

And then before plotting:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1])
```

As it's stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576059/reverse-the-order-of-legend).