# How to reverse order of legend for horizontal stacked bar chart in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I have the following code that generates a horizontal stacked bar chart in python, using seaborn.

```
sns.set_style('white')
    ax = sns.histplot(
        data=temp, y='tmp', weights='Weight', hue=field,
        multiple='stack', palette='viridis', shrink=0.75
    )
    
    ax.set_xlabel('Weight')
    ax.set_ylabel('{}_{}'.format(df, attribute))
    ax.set_title('plot distribution')

    sns.move_legend(ax, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.97))
    sns.despine()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

This generates the following horizontal stacked bar chart:
[image]

I would like to reverse the order of the legend, so that 10.0 is on top, and 0.0 is on the bottom, so reverse chronological order, reflecting the actual plot itself more intuitively.

I have tried the following:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], title='Line', loc='upper left')
```

referenced from this Stackoverflow post: [Reverse the order of a legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576059/reverse-the-order-of-a-legend)

But all this did was just remove the legend.

How can I properly reverse the order of the legend categories?

Comment: Is your question still open?

Answer (score 0):

## For current matplotlib and seaborn

With seaborn 0.13 and matplotlib >= 3.7 you can use `sns.move_legend(..., reverse=True)` to reverse the order of the legend elements. Note that `ax.legend(...)` (or the equivalent `plt.legend(...)` which operates on the "current ax"), will remove the legend. `ax.legend()` would create a legend from "labeled" matplotlib elements, while here seaborn has created its own custom legend.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style('white')
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.histplot(
    data=tips, y='time', weights='tip', hue='day',
    multiple='stack', palette='viridis', shrink=0.75
)
sns.move_legend(ax, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.97), reverse=True)
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn with reversed legend]

## For older versions

As `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` doesn't work here, you could grab the handles and labels from the legend created by seaborn:

```py
handles = ax.legend_.legendHandles
labels = [elt.get_text() for elt in ax.legend_.texts]
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.97))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `plt.legend()` like the following before your `plt.show()`:

```
plt.legend(reverse=True)
```

This was implemented from `matplotlib-3.7`, so keep that in mind.

[image]

follow their documentation to know more: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html#examples-using-matplotlib-pyplot-legend

Comment: I tried this and received the following error pointing to this new line: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reverse'`

Comment: via `sys.version` I am running `3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: sorry, my bad. I forgo to mention, this feature was implemented from `matplotlib-3.7`. so you will need `matplotlib>=3.7`